# root ubislate 7CI with android 4.1.1

Tags: rooting, ubislate

I have one table UBISLATE 7CI (DATAWIND IC: 12016A-7CI) and I need a step by step method or program to root the device. I was trying with some suggestion but I can't find a right method.

Anybody know the way?

Answer (score 0):

The rooting process of Android devices has become easy these days. Look into these links:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1997403

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460

According to the 2nd link, the person has developed a script to root devices with ease.

The procedure is to:

> Download file. 
> Extract it. 
> Click RunMe.bat file. 
> Choose Normal mode.
>   
> Follow steps as instructed and done.

Things to remember: 
a) Make sure you've:
-> ticked "USB Debugging" in Developers Options in Settings
-> ADB drivers are installed.

b) This process will **void warranty** and **might brick your tablet**.

All the best!

Comment: thks but are you sure that it's work on ubislate 7ci? because your links mentions Xperia and not ubislate.

Comment: sorry for such a late reply. Well if you have seen the first link, the second link APPEARED in the first link by a guy who claims to have successfully rooted the tablet. Although it maybe of Xperia group, at your own cause, take that risk.

You never know the outcome right